# 403 when using spring boot, but works well with postman

Tags: java, spring

Im making api call with postman on url:

```
https://cex.io/api/order_book/BTC/USD
```

plain GET no headers no params no nothing. But the same with java:

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
rt.getForObject("https://cex.io/api/order_book/BTC/USD", String.class);
```

gets me 403. where is the problem?

Comment: What is the returned HTTP code with Postman ? Should be the same.

Comment: From their [api documentation](https://cex.io/cex-api) - they do have rate limiting in place, limiting you to 600 requests per 10 minutes. Might be you exceeded that during testing.

Comment: im nowhere near 600, http code from postman is 200ok

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RestTemplate sets "User-Agent: Java_version" header, and it seems the site you are trying to query denies access with that user-agent.

You can explicitly set a user-agent instead of the default one like:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("User-agent", "SomeUserAgent");
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
    String result = rt.exchange("https://cex.io/api/order_book/BTC/USD", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer

Comment: yep, this was the problem!